# How to solve CORS policy blocked : Cross origin requests

Tags: angular, laravel

I'm in developpment of an application with laravel 9 backend as api and angular 14 frontend and actually I'm getting this error when I try to get the api ressources from my angular app

I'm using the HttpClient on angular to get the data

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8000/api/formations/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.*

I try many things that I found from the internet but those didn't work
such as :

adding to xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf those lines:

**Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding, X-Login-Origin, responseType"

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"**

I did this also :
[https://dev.to/keikesu0122/a-simple-way-to-enable-cors-on-laravel-55i#:~:text=The%20simplest%20method%20to%20enable,%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fhogehoge.com%20](https://dev.to/keikesu0122/a-simple-way-to-enable-cors-on-laravel-55i#:%7E:text=The%20simplest%20method%20to%20enable,%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fhogehoge.com%20).
I followed all the process
in middleware/cors.php:

```
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
    }
}
```

in Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

in routes/api.php:

```
Route::middleware(['cors'])->group(function(){
// formations
Route::get('/formations', [FormationController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/formations/{id}', [FormationController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('/formations/store', [FormationController::class, 'store']);
Route::put('/formations/{id}', [FormationController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/formations/{id}', [FormationController::class, 'destroy']);
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

I also get some extension of browser like:
[image]

When I test the cors request on my browser, on https://webbrowsertools.com/test-cors/
The cors isn't blocked isn't blocked
[image]

But I still get the error message, please help me

Answer (score 1):

I found that the solution was just to add
http://localhost:8000/api/formations/ in my httpClient on Angular
instead of just localhost:8000/api/formations/